# Get all Images from WebPage Program | Java

Tags: java, image, extract

Currently I need a program that given a URL, returns a list of all the images on the webpage.

ie:

logo.png
gallery1.jpg
test.gif

Is there any open source software available before I try and code something?

Language should be java. Thanks
Philip

Comment: Do you need a program or a library?

Comment: How do you mean sorry? I just need a .jar file or something that I can link into an existing Java program Im writing. Id imagine the program would be fairly simple, I just need to operation of image extraction

Comment: I don't think you will find any such library that exactly suits your scenario. You will have to use a parser and write some downloading code yourself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) has [`HtmlPage.getElementsByTagName("img")`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage.html#getElementsByTagName%28java.lang.String%29), which will probably suit you.

(read the short [Get started](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html) guide to see how to obtain the correct `HtmlPage` object)

Answer (score 14):

Just use a [simple HTML parser](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers), like [jTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/), and then [get all elements by tag name](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/w3c/tidy/DOMElementImpl.html#getElementsByTagName%28java.lang.String%29) `img` and then collect the `src` attribute of each in a `List<String>` or maybe `List<URI>`.

You can obtain an `InputStream` of an `URL` using [`URL#openStream()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29) and then feed it to any HTML parser you like to use. Here's a kickoff example:

```
InputStream input = new URL("http://www.stackoverflow.com").openStream();
Document document = new Tidy().parseDOM(input, null);
NodeList imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
List<String> srcs = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < imgs.getLength(); i++) {
    srcs.add(imgs.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("src").getNodeValue());
}

for (String src: srcs) {
    System.out.println(src);
}
```

I must however admit that HtmlUnit as suggested by Bozho indeed looks better.

Comment: and htmlunit is doing roughly what your answer tells, so +1 for clarifying what exactly should happen.

Comment: HtmlUnit is however less bloated than jTidy. It offers *builtin* ways to open a webpage and obtaining elements/attributes of interest using XPath.

Answer (score 4):

This is dead simple with [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) (and any other decent HTML parser):

```
Parser parser = new Parser("http://www.yahoo.com/");
NodeList list = parser.parse(new TagNameFilter("IMG"));

for ( SimpleNodeIterator iterator = list.elements(); iterator.hasMoreNodes(); ) {
    Tag tag = (Tag) iterator.nextNode();
    System.out.println(tag.getAttribute("src"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) that has a lot of options available.

Or google for [java wget](http://code.google.com/p/wget-java/) ...

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the HTML, and collect all SRC attributes of IMG elements in a Collection. Then download each resource from each url and write it to a file. For parsing there are several HTML parsers available, [Cobra](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra.jsp) is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

With Open Graph tags and HTML unit, you can extract your data really easily (PageMeta is a simple POJO holding the results):

```
    Parser parser = new Parser(url);

    PageMeta pageMeta = new PageMeta();
    pageMeta.setUrl(url);

    NodeList meta = parser.parse(new TagNameFilter("meta"));
    for (SimpleNodeIterator iterator = meta.elements(); iterator.hasMoreNodes(); ) {
        Tag tag = (Tag) iterator.nextNode();

        if ("og:image".equals(tag.getAttribute("property"))) {
            pageMeta.setImageUrl(tag.getAttribute("content"));
        }

        if ("og:title".equals(tag.getAttribute("property"))) {
            pageMeta.setTitle(tag.getAttribute("content"));
        }

        if ("og:description".equals(tag.getAttribute("property"))) {
            pageMeta.setDescription(tag.getAttribute("content"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use regular expression in Java

```html
<html>
<body>
<p>
<img src="38220.png" alt="test" title="test" /> 
<img src="32222.png" alt="test" title="test" />
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

```
    String s ="html";  //above html content
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<img [^>]*src=[\\\"']([^\\\"^']*)");
    Matcher  m = p.matcher (s);
    while (m.find()) {
        String src = m.group();
        int startIndex = src.indexOf("src=") + 5;
        String srcTag = src.substring(startIndex, src.length());
        System.out.println( srcTag );
    }
```