# How to automate the process of downloading a image based on its name using web scraping?

Tags: web-scraping

I am learning basics of web scraping. I would like to automate following process

1. Go to a site for example: http://www.vesseltracker.com
2. Provide the vessel name or MMSI number
3. Download the image of the vessel
4. Repeat this process

I followed the

[Get all Images from WebPage Program | Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172733/get-all-images-from-webpage-program-java)

link to get the basic but with little success. Could any one provide me with example in java??

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

Either of the examples on the [stack-overflow question that you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172733/get-all-images-from-webpage-program-java) should work for downloading images. Simply replace the `System.out.println` line with Ben Noland's `saveUrl` function from [this stack-overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java).

If you want a specific image, you'll need to determine how you want to filter it out from the others. Perhaps only save the images that contain `/vessel/` in the url?